# How to reset Apple Developer Enrollment to start step

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-developer

The problem is that Apple does not charge money for the developer account. I tried to pay twice but I didn't have success. Apple says "Your purchase may take up to 48 hours to process." but nothing happens. 
I assume that the Card Holder (Visa, Master Card) and developer name are different that is why Apple does not take the money.
So I want to reset enrollment to the first step, so I can write the same name as Card Holder name.

[image]

Comment: How to use a web page really doesn't seem like a programming question.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many issues behind the scene in your case,

1. Apple might not be able to obtain the payment from the card you have submitted .

   To prevent further issues:

• Before placing the new order, notify your financial institution that you are expecting a charge from Apple and confirm that your billing information is accurate.

• Be sure to use a payment method that is accepted for developer purchases in your region, as presented during the purchase process.

• Confirm that all payment details match the information on file with your financial institution when submitting the new order.

2. If there is mismatch in the card holder detail and the developer name, there may be chances that Apple might ask for ID proof of the developer(Rarely).
3. You can always contact the Developer apple customer care and check the issue , which will be resolved within 2 business working days.

Once you have made the payment , you have to wait upto 48 hours to process . You will not have option to reset the enrolment in this time.